# Inject specific values from custom configuration tree

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure some settings for a Spring Boot application:

```yaml
# application.yaml
application:
  services:
    - name: foo
      hostname: bar
    ...
```

I'm looking for a way, if possible, to inject this config directly, provided I have a type that models the same:

```java
class Service { String name; String hostname; }
```

Basically, what I'm looking for is to avoid injecting the class that manages all the configuration (`@ConfigurationProperties AppProperties` in my case), look for that field, and then filter by the `name` — basically if there is a way to `application.services.name = foo` somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Value` to **read properties from yaml file**.

```java
@Value("${application.services.name}")
private String name;
```

I hope this helps